# Function including randomness and guards

Tags: haskell, random, types

Hey I'm just trying to make a function that randomly returns a string.
I'm also pretty new to Haskell, I'm also wondering what the explicit type definition may look like for something like this.

```
randomSentence
| rando == 1 = "Who should I train at the beginning of Fire Emblem Awakened? "
| rando == 2 = "You rocked the socks of this question, Thank you for your help. Honest."
| rando == 3 = "If the keyboard was playing music while you were helping me, I bet it'd be the sickest bar."
| otherwise == 4 = "You've made the world a better place for contributing. Be proud."
where   rando = randomR (0,4)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how `IO` works yet?

Comment: After quickly reading up (learnyouahaskell) the IO page, I'm guessing along the lines of I have to stick this in a do?

Comment: `do` doesn't necessarily imply monadic code, but usually.

Comment: @TheInternet, `do` currently does imply that, but `do` is not required for I/O--it's just syntactic sugar for various applications of `>>=`.

Comment: Genesis, to be perfectly frank, I don't think you're quite ready for this yet. Spend some more time working with plain old functions and getting a feel for the type system and basic types and classes before delving into randomness.

Comment: @dfeuer, `do` does not necessarily imply monadic code, It can be used in simple functions, for example `> do do do do do 1 + 1` gives you `2`

Comment: @TheInternet, that is a peculiarly trivial and confusing use, but yes, I suppose you are correct.

Comment: @dfeuer, here's a less trivial one, when working with `let` - `in` become tedious, `do` is nice, http://lpaste.net/143095

Comment: @TheInternet I don't think that's less tedious than http://lpaste.net/143105. As far as I know, there isn't a nontrivial application of `do` outside of using it with a `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random generator must retrieve a pseudo random number from IO. This means your `String` must be returned in the `IO` monad.

```
import System.Random                                                                                                                                                              

randomSentence :: IO String                                                                                                                                                       
randomSentence = go <$> randomRIO (1,4)                                                                                                                                           
  where                                                                                                                                                                           
    go :: Int -> String                                                                                                                                                           
    go 1 = "Who should I train at the beginning of Fire Emblem Awakened? "                                                                                                        
    go 2 = "You rocked the socks of this question, Thank you for your help. Honest."                                                                                              
    go 3 = "If the keyboard was playing music while you were helping me, I bet it'd be the sickest bar."                                                                          
    go 4 = "You've made the world a better place for contributing. Be proud."
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html

Comment: The Internet, such a beautiful place for help. Thank you.
Mind if I get a little explanation on the go <?> randomIO (1,4) part?
It also sends a warning <interactive>

Comment: Sure, `go :: Int -> String` is applied over `randomRIO (1,4) :: IO Int`, which just so happens to be a `Functor` (since `IO` is a `Functor`). The `Functor` class has a method named `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so for our case `fmap` is specialized to look like `fmap :: (Int -> String) -> IO Int -> IO String`. Conceptually you can think of `fmap` as lifting the function `go` over the `IO` monad. It's a homomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

If you're new to Haskell, you might want to steer clear of random numbers for a bit, because it's one of those things that is simple in most languages but turns out to have a surprisingly steep learning curve in Haskell.  I'd recommend this progression:

1. Learn the basics of how to use the `IO` type in Haskell.  Otherwise you'll be completely at a loss on how to use random number generators at all.
2. When you feel comfortable with that, write some programs that use the `IO`-based random number generators from the `System.Random` package (which is what [The Internet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159854/1094403) is demonstrating).
3. Learn how to use a few monads like `State`, `Reader` and so on.

   - A bit more advanced: learn how to use monad transformers as well.  You can tackle that at this time or later as you choose.
4. When you feel comfortable with that, you will have a good chance of using [the `MonadRandom` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom), which makes working with random number generators much more convenient.
5. When you feel comfortable with that, you can try this exercise: write your own version of that library's `Rand` monad using the `State`.

That'll take some time, but by the time you're done with (5) you'll understand what's going on fairly well—and most of the knowledge transfers to other things in Haskell, not just to random numbers.

Comment: Methinks `State` would probably be good to work with before randomness.

Comment: Wow the direction in this post is incredible, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as is, cannot be given a *sensible* type signature because it does not quite make sense. Let's start from the beginning, defining a function mapping message ID to message:

```
message :: Int -> String
message 0 = "Who should I..."
message 1 = "You rocked..."
message 2 = "If the keyboard..."
message _ = "You've made the world..."
```

I decided to start from zero because that's the more common convention—it's not really necessary.

Now the only part remaining is the hard one: getting a random number. There are two steps: getting a randomness generator (which includes a seed), and then using that generator to get random numbers and new generators. If you use the popular `tf-random` package, you get the initial generator by executing the `IO` action `newTFGen`. Once you have that generator, `g`, you can use `randomR (0, 3) g` to get both a random number and a new generator to use to make the next random number. Note that if you accidentally reuse the old generator, you'll get exactly the same result out of it each time.